# Why didn’t he use alcohol to light the lighthouse?

Tags: plot-explanation, petes-dragon-1977

In the animated 1977 *Pete’s Dragon* Eliot spat out the alcoholic beverage of a spout of flame. Why didn’t they try that during the hurricane to light the wick of the lighthouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that firespitting enhances the flame due to aeration, but it's not a sustainable heat source. A lighthouse wick would require more thermal energy than a single burst of firespitting can deliver.